# Is it possible to have icon in tkinter menubar in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu

What I get:

[image: Icons not displayed in menu]

My code:

```
self.menu_bar = tk.Menu(self)
...
self.read_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=False)
self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label='Read', underline=0, state=tk.DISABLED, menu=self.read_menu)
self.read_menu.add_command(label='First Page', underline=0, image=self.read_first_image, compound=tk.LEFT,
                           command=self.menu_read_first, accelerator='Home', state=tk.DISABLED)
self.read_menu.add_command(label='Last Page', underline=1, image=self.read_last_image, compound=tk.LEFT,
                           command=self.menu_read_last, accelerator='End')
self.read_menu.add_command(label='Next Page', underline=0, image=self.read_next_image, compound=tk.LEFT,
                           command=self.menu_read_next, accelerator='PgDn')
self.read_menu.add_command(label='Previous Page', underline=0, image=self.read_previous_image, compound=tk.LEFT,
                           command=self.menu_read_previous, accelerator='PgUp', state=tk.DISABLED)
...
self.menu_bar.add_separator()
self.menu_bar.add_command(command=self.menu_read_first, image=self.read_first_image, state=tk.DISABLED)
self.menu_bar.add_command(command=self.menu_read_previous, image=self.read_previous_image, state=tk.DISABLED)
self.menu_bar.add_command(command=self.menu_read_next, image=self.read_next_image)
self.menu_bar.add_command(command=self.menu_read_last, image=self.read_last_image)
```

As you can see, the separator and the Icons are not displayed in the topmenu, but are well displayed in the submenu

Am I doing something wrong or it is just impossible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is impossible to do what you want if you are on Windows. Tkinter won't allow you to add icons to the menubar. I think this is related to limitations in the windows API that the underlying tk library uses.

Note: menubars are designed for menus, not commands. Placing a command on a menubar will likely frustrate your users, because they will expect that clicking on an item will display a menu.

Comment: The question asks about adding an image to submenus instead of submenu names. That said, I agree with you -- it is impossible. And also, yes, he has also added commands to the submenu names which is wrong.

Comment: But what more interesting is that the `add_cascade` method of a menu object has an option [`image`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.add-method), but it does not show any image, it just shows a string "(Image)".

Comment: @ParvizKarimli: the question is about putting icons "in the topmenu:". Look at the screenshot and notice where the menubar has `{image}` instead of an actual image. That's what is being asked about, and that's what my answer addresses. You can't have commands or images in the actual menubar, only in dropdown menus.

Comment: I consider this as a weakness of Tkinter. Because when you look at the status bar on this page for example, you can see a menubar that contains submenus which have images instead of names: `StackExchange`, `INBOX`, and `ACHIEVEMENTS`. Also, again, it does not return any unknown option error, it just shows "(Image)" (string) instead of an image.

Comment: @ParvizKarimli: it may be a weakness in Tk, but it's a harmless weakness. Status bars are not menubars, so they can easily have different behavior. Menubars have a very specific behavior that most users expect.  The menubars take advantage of native APIs, so it could be that the windows API simply doesn't support images on the menubar of a window.

Comment: I wanted to save some space from having a menu and a toolbar by having the menu with textual entries and icons for the toolbar part like [http://i.imgur.com/j7RU2y5.jpg]

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, I know that windows has no such feature at all -- at least, I have never seen. But what I'm mostly curious about is that there is an [`image`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.add-method) option, but this option does not work. I'm afraid that I have understood it incorrectly -- perhaps, this option has a different feature.

Comment: @Cabu have you checked my answer? Does it really not solve your problem? I just checked out the image you provided above, and I think, it has pretty much same concept with the answer below.

Comment: @ParvizKarimli: the image option works, just not if the menu is used as a menubar. Images are supported in dropdown menus. Tkinter doesn't necessarily know the menu is going to be used as a menubar when the menu is created.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, that's what I was suspecting to be true.

Comment: @Parviz in your proposal, the button open submenu. I don't want submenu from the button, but direct action. The idea is to have the menu where you can navigate all the option and actions and the most useful commands as icons for direct action

Comment: @Cabu the first picture you provided above in your question has misled me, to be honest. And what you want to achieve now is possible to be accomplished using buttons (and giving these buttons proper geometries/positions and images you wish). Otherwise, it is not possible to put images as (menu items) identifiers on the menubar. It just was not designed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add an image to menubar, so the submenus of this menubar will have images instead of string names. However, you can use `Menubutton` widgets, and set their position close to the left top corner of the parent window to have a visually same view with a `Menu` object. Here's how you can achieve this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500-500+50")



imgvar1 = PhotoImage(file='airplane1.png')

mainmenu1 = Menubutton(root, image=imgvar1)
mainmenu1.grid(row=0, column=0)

submenu1 = Menu(mainmenu1)
mainmenu1.config(menu=submenu1)

submenu1.add_command(label="Option 1.1")
submenu1.add_command(label="Option 1.2")


imgvar2 = PhotoImage(file='automobile1.png')

mainmenu2 = Menubutton(root, image=imgvar2)
mainmenu2.grid(row=0, column=1)

submenu2 = Menu(mainmenu2)
mainmenu2.config(menu=submenu2)

submenu2.add_command(label="Option 2.1")
submenu2.add_command(label="Option 2.2")



imgvar = PhotoImage(file='eye.gif')
button = Button(root, image=imgvar)
button.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

Additionally, I consider this as a kind of bug in `Menu`, because `add_cascade` method of `Menu` has an option [`image`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.add-method), because it does not return any unknown option error, but it does not show any image either, it just shows a string: "(Image)".

Comment: I have tried this solution. It look good visually and does what I wanted to do. But in the meantime, I have lost menu shortcuts (eg: Alt+F to open the File submenu)

Comment: @Cabu I'm glad that my solution helps you! And I understand the last problem you are having. To solve this problem, you can use key bindings. I'm sure it's possible. Just keep in mind that, in programming everything is based on previous knowledge, like a chained reaction. So for example, `Alt+F` is a key binding of `Menu` widget. The letters in key bindings are the first letters of menu names.

Comment: @Cabu You can always bind the shortcuts to the root, and transmit them to the menu. To make it perfectly clean, I'd wrote a `dispatch_binding` in the root widget, and transmit each input to the right widget.

Answer (score 1):

working case :

```
self.MyImage,self.dictImg={},{}

self.ypath='path'

self.dictImg[0]='img0.png'

self.MyImage['Option'] =PhotoImage(file=self.ypath+os.sep+self.dictImg[0])
        self.casmenu.choices.wierdones.add_command(label='Option',image=self.MyImage['Option'],compound='left')
```

please note: you must indicate `compound='left'`, the relative option  to the `image=self.MyImage['Option']`.

Answer (score 0):

## note: icon image must be .png, try 10x10 px, resolution min 150

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *


your_app_name = Tk()
menubar = Menu(your_app_name)

file = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Command", menu=file_menu)
icon = PhotoImage(file='your_file.png') # or: (file='./your_file.png')
file_menu.add_command(label='New', image=icon, compound='left', command=some_function)

your_app_name.config(menu=menubar)
your_app_name.mainloop()
```